# Why does my running clock measuring function give me 0 clocks?

Tags: c, clock

I'm doing some exercise projects in a C book, and I was asked to write a program that uses clock function in C library to measure how long it takes qsort function to sort an array that's reversed from a sorted state. So I wrote below:

```
/* 
 * Write a program that uses the clock function to measure how long it takes qsort to sort
 * an array of 1000 integers that are originally in reverse order. Run the program for arrays
 * of 10000 and 100000 integers as well.
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SIZE 10000

int compf(const void *, const void *);

int main(void)
{
    int arr[SIZE];
    clock_t start_clock, end_clock;

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
        arr[i] = SIZE - i;
    }

    start_clock = clock();
    qsort(arr, SIZE, sizeof(arr[0]), compf);
    end_clock = clock();
    printf("start_clock: %ld\nend_clock: %ld\n", start_clock, end_clock);
    printf("Measured seconds used: %g\n", (end_clock - start_clock) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int compf(const void *p, const void *q)
{
    return *(int *)p - *(int *)q;
}
```

But running the program gives me the results below:

```
start_clock: 0          
end_clock: 0         
Measured clock used: 0
```

How can it be my system used 0 clock to sort an array? What am I doing wrong?
I'm using GCC included in mingw-w64 which is x86_64-8.1.0-release-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0.
Also I'm compiling with arguments `-g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO` given to `gcc.exe`.

Comment: cannot reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/qosdqb4q6

Comment: On my system I get non-zero measurements - if you increase `SIZE` by a multiple of 10 do you still get zero?

Comment: depends on the clock precision

Comment: I also can't reproduce this.  I don't see why your build arguments would affect this either.  What environment are you running on?

Comment: IF you `#define SIZE 1000000` (assuming you can *VLA* such an array) do you get the same result?

Comment: @pmg — the array is not a VLA.  It is just a regular, fixed-size array.  Given that the platform is Windows, it's probable that the maximum stack size is 1 MiB, so bumping the size to 1 million would fail.  However, there's nothing to stop the array being allocated at file scope, in which case the size can be larger (1 million numbers should not then be a problem).

Comment: Jaeho Choi, Use a specified matching  print specifier `printf("clock: %ld\n", (long) start_clock);`

Comment: Jaeho Choi, Perhaps code is optimized resulting in 0 time to sort?  Try `arr[i] = SIZE - i;` --> `arr[i] = rand()`.

Comment: @pmg I tried setting the array size of 100,000 500,000 1,000,000 and results were start_clock: 0 end_clock: 1 Measured clock used: 0.001, start_clock: 2, end_clock: 14, Measured clock used: 0.012 and the last one exited with code 1, respectively.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica start_clock and end_clock variables are of type clock_t, which is defined by typedef long clock_t in time.h in my standard library already. Also tried using rand() function with the array of 10,000 integers but this also gave me 0, 0, 0 result.

Comment: @Martin I compiled and ran on my desktop, which  I'm using Windows 10 21H1, and the compiler is gcc as I described in the post. Is there any environment setting that could affect this that I didn't mention?

Comment: @DanielKleinstein  I tried setting the array size of 100,000 500,000 1,000,000 and results were start_clock: 0 end_clock: 1 Measured clock used: 0.001, start_clock: 2, end_clock: 14, Measured clock used: 0.012 and the last one exited with code 1, respectively

Comment: @JaehoChoi Sounds like you have a fast machine, that's all.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I do have a fast CPU, which is intel i9-10850K@5.0GHz, but does this mean I'd get 0 as the clock count after sorting as well? I was expecting the result would be something like start_clock:0, end_clock:numbers at some thousands, total_time: very few microseconds, but 0, 0, 0 though.

Comment: @JaehoChoi Trye some much larger sorts. Use  _allocated_ memory like `n = 10000000; /* 30000000, 100000000 */ = int *arr = malloc(sizeof *arr * n);`

Answer (score 0):

3 possible answers to your issue:

1. what is clock_t? Is it just a normal data type like int? Or is it some sort of struct? Make sure you are using it correctly for its data type
2. What is this running on? If your clock isn't already running you need to start it on, for instance, most microcontrollers. If you try pulling from it without starting, it will just be 0 at all times since the clock is not moving
3. Is your code fast enough that it's not registering? Is it actually taking 0 seconds (rounded down) to run? 1 full second is a very long time in the coding world, you can run millions of lines of code in less than a second. Make sure your timing process can handle small numbers (ie. you can register 1 micro-second of timing), or your code is running slow enough to register on your clock speed

Comment: If `clock_t` was not a numeric type (was a structure type), the code would not compile.  So the answer to your (1) is "normal type".

Comment: Since the system is using a MinGW version of GCC, presumably the platform is Windows.

Comment: @jonathanLeffler This is not correct. You can print a datatype incorrectly, and the compiler will not complain. Likewise clock() could return the correct datatype automatically, which would not cause a compiler error. It's possible he's using the datatype correctly up until the PRINT statement, which is printing nonsense, like a struct-pointer for instance

Comment: The subtraction would fail if `clock_t` was a structure type.  You are correct, though, that if the type was not equivalent to `long`, the printing would fail — but the compiler options in most variants of GCC 8.1.0 would generate a warning if the `clock_t` values were not compatible with `long`.  I'd be happier if `-Werror` was one of the compiler options; it would be more certain that there isn't a warning being ignored.

Comment: @jonathanLeffler hmmmm, this is true. My mistake

Comment: The value of `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` would be useful data that the program should print for debugging purposes.  On an older MacBook Pro, I get a time of 253 µs for the 10,000 element array, but `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is 1 million on POSIX machines (for XSI-conformance, anyway: see [`<time.h>`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/time.h.html)).  I wonder if it is just 100 or 1000 on MinGW?

Comment: "what is clock_t?" --> "real types capable of representing times"  C17 - not a `struct/union`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica what type would that be, then? Do you know? Are we talking int or a float

Comment: @MikeStallone Yes -  `clock_t` either FP or _integer_, `long, double, long long` etc, (not complex, pointers, struct, union). An _integer_ more common than FP.   `clock_t` unlikely to be `short, float` to due such a small precision.

Comment: 1. clock_t in my copy of gcc is long integer which is defined in time.h ```typedef long clock_t```

Comment: 2. Desktop, Windows 10 version 21H1, also tried increasing SIZE to 100,000 and 500,000 and in these cases the program gave non-zero results, so I think it's not the clock is not running

Comment: 3. How do I check if timing process can handle small numbers? I think the problem is that start_clock and end_clock variables are both set to be zero which should be return values of clock() function in runtime. @JonathanLeffler CLOCKS_PER_SEC is a macro that expands to 1000 in my copy of time.h which is from mingw-w64.

Comment: If the value of CLOCKS_PER_SEC is 1000, you can at best time to 1-millisecond accuracy.  If your sorting process takes less than that, you'll usually only get zeros out of it; occasionally, perhaps, a 1 millisecond time.  You often want to ensure that you get a good multiple of the minimum time granule in your timing (tens or even better hundreds as the multiple).  In this case, you might have to repeat the test 1000 times between calls to `clock()`, with one timing the array setting and no sort, and the other for array setting _and_ sorting.  This allows you to see how the times compare.

Comment: The only complication is that for a loop like the array-setting loop, the optimizer might spot that the result of 'set only' is not used, and might eliminate the code, making the timing moot as the loops are not present.  Fixing that sort of cleverness can be tricky.  Sometimes, separate compilation — putting the array-setting loop into a function in a separate file, and calling that function from the main test code — is sufficient, but you may not want to use LTO (link-time optimization) on the program.  Timing code can be tricky, to be polite about it.